# Passing a pointer to struct as a parameter to a function in C

Tags: c

When passing a pointer to`struct` as a parameter to a function what is the point of using that parenthesis `(*t).name` in the `printf`.

I'm confused about what is the difference between `(*t).name` ,`*(t).name` and `t.name`.

```
typdef struct{
 const char *name;
 }phone;

 void update(phone *t){
 printf("Name %s!,(*t).name);
 }
```

Comment: Your title is misleading. You are passing *a pointer* to a struct as an *argument* to a function.

Comment: `printf("Name %s!", (*t).name);` or `printf("Name %s!", t->name);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function doesn't take the `struct` as a parameter, it takes a *pointer* to the struct. In order to use a pointer, you have to dereference it, and `*ptr` is used to dereference a pointer to access the object it points to.

```
(*t).name
```

is equivalent to:

```
t->name
```

which is the more common way to write it.

```
t.name
```

can't be used because `t` is not a structure, it's a pointer, and `.` can only be used with a structure.

```
*(t).name
```

is wrong because `.` has higher precedence than `*`, so it's equivalent to:

```
*(t.name)
```

I suggest you go back to your textbook or tutorial, and reread the chapter on pointers.

Comment: Is this two equivalent `(*t).name` and `*(t.name)`?

Comment: No they're not. As I wrote, `*(t.name)` is equivalent to `*(t).name`

Comment: @XERO Which is also equivalent to just `*t.name`.

Comment: Ok so this means that `(*t).name = *(t.name)=*t.name`?

Comment: No, they're not all equivalent.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about misleading I was a bit tired. It's clear from your first comment that this two was not equivalent `(*t).name and *(t.name)`. With my second comment I wrote wrong. From the @HolyBlackCat comment and yours together I understand so that these three must be equivalent. `*(t).name = *(t.name)=*t.name`. or? Thanks for your time